# How to count the number of Grandchildren

Tags: reactjs

New to React and JSX so apologies if this is a very basic question.

I have a "GrandParent" node and I can count the number of "Parent" nodes using:

```
 {React.Children.count(this.props.children)
```

However - given a particular "Parent" - how can I return the count of their children?
I can do it at the parent level, but can't figure out how to do it at the GrandParent level.

As usual - probably best to explain by example, so I have an example at:
http://jsfiddle.net/zuoza31g/1/

I would like my output to be:

```
I am the grandfather 'Grandfather'
I have '1' children
I have '4' grandchildren

I am the father 'Father' 
I have '4' children

I am a son 'Son 1'
I am a son 'Son 2'
I am a son 'Son 3'
I am a son 'Son 4'
```

It's part of a much bigger problem, so I'm simplified it down to this example ..

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can count the number of grand children using following code:

```
    var count = 0;
    React.Children.forEach(this.props.children, function (child){
        count = count + React.Children.count(child.props.children);
    });
```

Here is your fiddle with this solution implemented: http://jsfiddle.net/db8o8920/